# epoch to date on mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, date, datetime, datetime-format

I've tried using

```
FROM_UNIXTIME(`date`)
```

and got a yyyy/mm/dd hour

how can I reverse it, that is have it as

hh:mm:secs mm/dd/yyyy

Thanks

Answer (score 11):

Add specifiers to [`FROM_UNIXTIME`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_from-unixtime) or use [`DATE_FORMAT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format):

**Specifiers**

```
%T  Time, 24-hour (hh:mm:ss)
%m  Month, numeric (00..12)
%d  Day of the month, numeric (00..31)
%Y  Year, numeric, four digits
```

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(`date`), '%T %m/%d/%Y)
```

Or

```
SELECT FROM_UNIXTIME(`date`, '%T %m/%d/%Y')
```

Comment: coming back, this is the best, shortest, least confusing code answer

Answer (score 3):

Use [`DATE_FORMAT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format)

```
DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(`date`), "%T %m/%d/%Y")
```

This will return hh:mm:ss dd/mm/YYYY from unix time stored in database.

Answer (score 1):

you have to define your custom date/time format. please have a look at:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_from-unixtime

SELECT FROM_UNIXTIME(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(), '%h:%i:%s %M/%D/%Y');

Comment: Also a viable alternative.

Comment: thats nice..however I do I avoid the 31st notation and have as 31?

Comment: @user1432779 See my answer for specifiers.